# Page reload occurs before request finishes

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax, forms

I wrote a plugin to send an invitation to a friend and am submitting a form using AJAX and used the tips talked about in [5 tips for using AJAX in wordpress](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) and another article referenced in the AJAX in plugins wordpress codex page.

I have now got the relevant code executing and sending an email as expected however the page reloads before the AJAX call finishes.

The relevant PHP code is here:

```
<?php
define( 'SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION', '3.1.1' );
define( 'SEND_INVITATION_PLUGIN_URL', plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) );

// Tie into WordPress Hooks and any functions that should run on load.
//
add_action( 'init', array( 'NC_SendInvitation', 'send_invitation_init' ) );

class NC_SendInvitation {
    protected $nonce_name = 'send_invitation';
    protected $post_url = '';

    public static function send_invitation_init() {
        new self;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->send_invitation_head();
        $this->send_invitation_check_wordpress_version();
        add_action( 'show_invitation_form', array( $this, 'send_invitation_get_form' ), 10, 1 );

        // Add AJAX actions
        // Serves logged in users
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_form_action', array( $this, 'send_invitation_handle_submit' ) );

        // Serves non-logged in users
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_form_action', array( $this, 'send_invitation_handle_submit' ) );
    }

    public function send_invitation_head() {
         // Add script that for handling AJAX POST request to the head
        wp_enqueue_script( 'send-invitation-ajax-handle',
            plugins_url( 'js/ajax.js', __FILE__ ),
            array( 'jquery' ) );

        // Localise script find out what this does
        wp_localize_script( 'send-invitation-ajax-handle',
            'send_invitation_ajax_script',
            array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

        // Add the script for showing and hiding the form to the head
        wp_enqueue_script( 'send-invitation-js',
            plugins_url( 'js/send-invitation.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' ) );

        // Add the CSS that styles the form to the head
        wp_enqueue_style( 'send-invitation',
            plugins_url( 'css/send-invitation.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }

    public function send_invitation_check_wordpress_version() {
        global $wp_version;

      $exit_msg = 'Send Invitation requires version '
    . SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION
    . 'or newer <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress">Please
update!</a>';

    if ( version_compare( $wp_version, SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION, '<') )
    {
        exit( $exit_msg );
    }
}

    public function send_invitation_get_form($post_url) {
    // TODO Try moving this into another file and include here using method above
    $send_invitation_form ='
    <h1><a href="#" onclick="show_form();">Send Invitation</a></h1>
    <form id="invitation-form" action="" method="post">
        <p>
            Your Email Address<br />
            <input type="text" name="your_email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Email Address of Recipient<br />
            <input type="text" name="friends_email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Subject<br />
            <input type="text" name="subject" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Message<br/>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="message">' . $post_url . '</textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="send_invitation" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="form_action" />
        <p><input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="send_invitation();" /></p>
    </form>
    <div class="response-area">
        <span class="error"></span>
        <span class="success"></span>
    </div>';

    echo $send_invitation_form;
}

    public function send_invitation_handle_submit() {
    $success = __('OK');
    $error = __('NOT OK');
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        try {
            error_log('Inside if', 0);
            $to = $_POST['friends_email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            // TODO Suppress error message with @
            $send_result = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            $feedback = $send_result ? $success : $error;
        }
        catch( Exception $e ) {
            $feedback = "Catch: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $feedback = "Error: " . $error;
    }
    echo $feedback;
    exit;
    // Do not forget to exit
}
?>
```

The relevant javascript code is here:

```
function send_invitation() {
    alert("got here");
    jQuery.post(send_invitation_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        jQuery('#invitation-form').serialize(),
        function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
            jQuery('.response-area .success').html(response);
        }
    );
}
```

Another problem I am seeing is that the POST request to the ajaxurl shows up red in firebug but it disappears quickly and I cannot see what is happening but the correct PHP functions are executing but no response comes back and all I get is page reload once the request is sent.

I am not sure why this is the case but I have tried debugging this for a while and could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance.
nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using ajaxForm instead which does not suffer from any reload problems. Moreover, it is also included with a wordpress as an available plugin so its well integrated.

Comment: 's could you please elaborate on your "using ajaxForm instead" answer?
Did you simply use it instead of .post? To me the documentation is not clear on the [ajaxForm plugin site](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) and how to use the action: option (which I think is an invention of wordpress. Thanks, Ron

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
return false;
```

at the end of the js function send_invitation() to prevent default reload action

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am afraid this did not change anything. The page still reloads, the email is still sent and the call to admin-ajax.php still shows up red on firebug.